# Build QT4.8.6 with VS2019 gives errors

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2019

I am using VS2019 and Qt5.11.1 on my computer. I can create and compile code if I create new any Qt application(it would be Qt.5.11.1) from VS2019 but when I try to build Qt4.8.6 code in VS2019 but it gives me errors.
I install qt-vs-addin-msvc2019-2.6.0 for compiling and from VS2019 side I added msvc2017_64 as an extension. The problem is program cannot find  headers as seen from picture [png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRKGL.png). What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to install [Qt4.8.6](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.6/) binaries and headers (and probably vs2010 compiler)

Comment: According to your guidance I installed both binaries/headers and vs2010 compiler. All the errors gone related to that. But now I faced with another error while compiling VS2010 solution. In addition to your advice, I also make the platform VS2010 from General Properties > Platform Toolset > Visual Studio 2010 and it is working! Thanks.